# pt-table-checksum from remote server

Tags: mysql, percona-tools

I am using pt-table-checksum for the first time and have some questions that I can't seem to resolve by reading the documentation on Percona's website.

Per the documentation, pt-table-checksum performs an online replication consistency check by executing checksum queries on the master. Does this script have to be run on the master? Can I run from another server that has no MySQL installed? I tried this:

pt-table-checksum --host=mysqlistance --user=user --password=password --replicate-check-only

But I get some errors indicated that it is unable to connect to the localhost. However, it specifies the IP instead of localhost.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a mysql user that has permissions from the host your executing the script from.

Run `select user, host from mysql.user` on the database to see if your user has an entry for the IP you're connecting from. If not, you will have to grant permissions to the user for that host.